# Class Declaration and Usage

Tags: swift, class, watchos

Newbie question. I am simply trying to declare a class (or even struct) as a separate Swift file and then build it or use it inside a separate class. Consider this:

```
import Foundation

class PayloadTest{
    var label: String
    init(label:String) {
          self.label = label
    }
}
```

---- then separate file

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


class InterfaceController2: WKInterfaceController {

    var payloadtest = PayloadTest(label: "test string init")

    payloadtest.label = "test" // this line gives error - says it was expecting a declaration
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I can't figure out why if I make a class or struct at the same level in my watchOS extension, it is not allowed to be accessed or recognized when I try to access the variables.

Comment: You need to brush up on various scope concepts. Try making you class a public one, (of course) you'll also need to expose the various things inside to too. Other levels of exposure include internal, fileprivate, and private. In Swift 3 the definitions of fileprivate (not available in 2.x) may yet be different come Swift 4, so be careful. (Yes, separate files for your classes mean each class is private by default.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **dfd** mentioned in the comment section this is a scope issue. In many programming languages you just can't write statements (expressions) which is not either a declaration or initialization or a method call outside the function or a method.

Let me explain what I said,

In a class or a structure definition any statements(expressions) apart from declaration & initialization should be present in the function (method) definition.

```
class PayloadTest{
//The below statement is declaration, which declares label is an property of type string.
  var label: String
  init(label:String) {
//The below statement is an assignment, and it compiles and execute fine as this is inside a init method.
        self.label = label
  }
}
```

However in your second snippet,

import WatchKit
import Foundation

```
class InterfaceController2: WKInterfaceController {

//The below statement compiles fine even tough it isn't present inside a method coz it is initialization statement.

var payloadtest = PayloadTest(label: "test string init")

//However the compiler complains about the below assignment statement because, this is neither an declaration nor an initialization statement and it should not be outside method.
//So you've to keep this statement inside a method for compiler to stop complaining.

payloadtest.label = "test" // this line gives error - says it was expecting a declaration
....
}
```

To make the second snippet work put the below line of code in a method and call that method,

```
payloadtest.label = "test"
```

**So always remember any statements apart from declaration, initialization should be present inside a method or function definition** and this applies to most of the languages.

Please go through the various scope levels present. HTH :)

Comment: this definitely helped me understand the issue. I appreciate the fast and full response to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an expression nested in a class like that. You can get around this by putting your code in a closure which you immediately call:

class InterfaceController2: WKInterfaceController {

```
var payloadtest = {
    let pt = PayloadTest(label: "test string init")
    pt.label = "test"
    return pt
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to move that code in a function. (Swift 3.0 version)

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

  var payloadtest = PayloadTest(label: "test string init")


  fileprivate func test() {
    payloadtest.label = "test" // tape this line in a function
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code work with optional type -

```
class PayloadTest {
    var label: String?
    init(label:String) {
        self.label = label
    }
}
```

[image: Output with the code.]

Comment: Hi Anand, how does making label optional, solves the problem? Please go through the question.

Comment: I already goes through the question and after that gave my answer that person not able to access the variable i worked on and got the same issue after that i found the solution and post my answer here. @iamyogish

Comment: He's not able to access the payloadtest.label = "test", the label property of Payloadtest not because it is not optional, he is trying to write a executable statement inside a class scope. And this will not work since any executable statement apart from declaration, initialization should be present inside a function.